# StoreServicesFeedbackLauncher is not working

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

Since Windows 10, Version 1809 (Build 17763), the start of the Feedback Hub from a UWP app has ended with the following error: -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'

```
if (StoreServicesFeedbackLauncher.IsSupported())
{
      FeedbackRadioButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private async void LaunchFeedbackHub(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {                
        var launcher = StoreServicesFeedbackLauncher.GetDefault();
        await launcher.LaunchAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

There is a reference to the `Microsoft.Engagment.Framework` and the `Microsoft.Services.Store.SDK` is installed.
The problem occurs in both debug mode and release mode.

What could that be?

Comment: call [IsSupported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.services.store.engagement.storeservicesfeedbacklauncher.issupported#Microsoft_Services_Store_Engagement_StoreServicesFeedbackLauncher_IsSupported) to see if Hub is installed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback, I have reported this to related team. Please pay attention to the follow-up version update. Currently, you could use the following  wrokaround.

```
switch (AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily)
{
    case "Windows.Mobile":

        await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("windows-feedback:?contextid=30"));
        break;
    case "Windows.Desktop":

        await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("windows-feedback:?contextid=143"));
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the same functionality though.

Comment: I don't understand you very much. can you describe it in detail?

Comment: Sorry, I just mean that this just opens the Feedback Hub but doesn't bring you to file a new issue for the specific app (like it does in the SDK).  Also, the SDK lets you attach metadata to that new issue, but this doesn't provide that either.

Comment: These contextIds should not be used in production code and should be documented in the answer above.

Answer (score 5):

**Update 2/16:** Microsoft has reversed course and fixed this in [Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Services.Store.Engagement/) 10.1901.28001.

---

**Original answer:**

This API is notoriously unreliable.

If possible, I recommend switching to a simpler [protocol launching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation) approach. Some examples (that induce the default activation type of `URIFeedbackHome`) have been provided below.

Launch Feedback Hub:

```
feedback-hub:
```

Launch Feedback Hub, with [Category: Apps] and [Subcategory: EarTrumpet]

```
feedback-hub://?appid=40459File-New-Project.EarTrumpet_1sdd7yawvg6ne!EarTrumpet
```

Launch Feedback Hub, with the Profile tab as active tab

```
feedback-hub://?tabid=6
```

There's no public information about the other more complex scenarios (e.g. providing key-value metadata, attaching screenshots, etc.) at this time.

Comment: It seems there's an official answer (not going to fix): https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-uwp/issues/1389#issuecomment-457346505 which makes Rafael's answer more relevant.